# Python regex for matching two or three white spaces

Tags: python, regex, string

I'm trying to match the following text with a regex in Python 2.7

```
SUBCASE   8
SUBCASE   9
SUBCASE  10
SUBCASE  11
```

The number of spaces between "subcase" and the number drops from 3 to 2. I'm trying to use this regex in Python:

`(SUBCASE)[\s+]([0-9]+)`

Where am I going wrong? Shouldn't the `\s+` mean "catch any white spaces more than one"?

Comment: Why not a simple [split](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)?

Comment: @Alexander I have an existing function (using regex) I want to make this change to so I want to maintain the same structure

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You'll want:

```
SUBCASE\s+([0-9]+)
```

or

```
SUBCASE\s+(\d+)
```

Putting `\s+` inside of `[...]` means, that you want precisely one symbol that either is a whitespace character, or a plus.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. When I manually add spaces (2 or 3) to my regex, it matches fine but \s+ doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you entering the string as a [raw string](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals)? Else you'll have to escape the backslash. Prefixing with an `r` gives you a raw string literal: `r'SUBCASE\s+(\d+)'`

Comment: @prrao: You also have an extraneous left parenthesis in your regex: `[(0-9]`. Change that to `[0-9]`.

Comment: @Sebastian It doesn't work either way, even if I enter as a raw string

Comment: @prrao: It works fine for me. You can see my test case here: http://ideone.com/EifKh

Comment: @Sebastian This snippet is part of a much larger file. Iterating over each line, I use `re.search(pattern, line).group()` to print matches. I don't compile the regex first. Is this an issue?

Comment: @prrao It's hard to say what the exact problem is without knowing more. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
(SUBCASE)\s+([0-9]+)
```

You used [\s+] which would do a character match of one whitespace or a + sign

Comment: '+' is the regex 'one or more' operator. He's not trying the match the '+' character.